# Boot device not found error on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am a rookie at Linux and started using Ubuntu just yesterday. I mistakenly set the swap partition as bootable on startup and now when I start the computer, it shows a Boot Device not found error. I use a dual booted pc with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

How do I fix this issue?Please help!

Comment: Grub does not use boot flag, but if UEFI, boot,esp flags must be on ESP - efi system partition or your FAT32 formatted partition. Use gparted on live installer and right click on ESP to change flags.  Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred thanks for the solution, it worked well for me and now it's working great!